# SQL Alchemy GIN index on (UUID, JSONB)

Tags: postgresql, sqlalchemy

I have a table with schema that has a `json` field. The filed has a lot of data populated to it already.

```
CREATE TABLE table(
id     UUID      NOT NULL
data    JSON       NOT NULL
);
```

I want to create an index for the json field. I have tried the script below

```
 __table_args__ = (
                  Index("index_table_on_data_gin",
                        "data",
                        postgresql_using='gin',),
               
                  ),
                   Index("index_table_on_id_gin",
                        "id",
                        postgresql_using='gin',),
               
                  ),
                  )
```

Here are the errors that I am getting.

JSON index creation error

```
sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.errors.UndefinedObject) data type json has no default operator class for access method "gin"
```

UUID index creation error

```
sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.errors.UndefinedObject) data type uuid has no default operator class for access method "gin"
```

Comment: I don't think you can create GIN indexes on these types, they only work on text types like `varchar` or `text` (try creating the indexes in psql and see).

Comment: [Quote from the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-json.html) "*In general, most applications should prefer to store JSON data as `jsonb`*"

Comment: A GIN index on a `uuid` column doesn't really make sense. What problem are you trying to solve with that?

Comment: I want to perform a fulltext search on the UUID.

Comment: You probably don't want to perform full text search on a `uuid`. A `uuid` is a 128 bit integer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [btree_gin](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/btree-gin.html) extension to index the UUID with GIN (though I don't see the point, why not just use regular btree for it?)

Comment: Thank you. I have used a normal btree for it. What are good cases for GIN index usage? `CREATE EXTENSION btree_gist` helped me with the UUID, then I added `postgresql_using='gist''

Answer (score 2):

You can't index the `json` type, but you can index the `jsonb` type instead, see the [manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-json.html#JSON-INDEXING). `jsonb` should be your preferred type (see the [manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-json.html))